# A Hash with many arrays

Tags: ruby, arrays

I am trying to define a structure that can create a one-to-many relationship, sort of. For example, let's say an organization named "ACO" has some stuff:

```
KEY_PERF_INDS = [ {'ACO' => [2,3,4] , [2,34,5]} ]
```

But this is syntactically wrong. Is it possible to write something that achieves this?

Comment: Is `ACO` supposed to be an array of sub-arrays?  `'ACO' => [ [2,3,4], [2,34,5] ]`

Comment: yeah that looks good. So I want to be able to have one structure that says ACO  ..these.... "HOSPITAL" ... those...."BLAH"...these...so I need one more layer around what you have, so I have many more of things like that "ACO" that them selves have many things like those numbers in the arryas

Comment: `HOSPITAL,BLAH` are at the same level as `ACO`? That's just more keys in the hash... `[{ 'ACO' => [[2,3,4],[3,4,5]], 'HOSPITAL' => [[1,2,3],[9,8]] }]`

Comment: Or, `KEY_PERF_INDS` itself should be a hash `{}` not an array.  `KEY_PERF_INDS = { 'ACO' => [[1,2,3],[4,5,6]], 'HOSPITAL' => [[3,2,1],[9,8,7]] }`

Comment: @MichaelBerkowski : Yes,  HOSPITAL,  BLAH, ... all at the same level as "ACO"....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your other groups `HOSPITAL, BLAH, ETC` (per the comments) are all to be at the same level as `ACO`, then the entire structure `KEY_PERF_INDS` should be a hash `{}` rather than an array `[]`.  Make each of those a key to the main hash, and each is an array containing sub-arrays.

```
# The main structure is a hash {}
KEY_PERF_INDS = { 
  'ACO' => [
    [1,2,3],
    [4,5,6]
  ], 
   'HOSPITAL' => [
    [3,2,1],
    [9,8,7]
  ],
  'BLAH' => [
    [99,88], 
    [11,22],
    [33,44]
  ]
}
```

Access these then as:

```
KEY_PERF_INDS['HOSPITAL'][1][2]
# prints 7

KEY_PERF_INDS['BLAH'].last.first
# prints 33
```